# CSS3 transitions not working well on div or image

Tags: javascript, css

I try to implement, with Javascript, CSS3 transitions in order to gray an image when mouse is not over `<img>` and render with colors when mouse is on it.

Here's my code snippet :

```
// Create container for image of simulation
var containerImage =  document.createElement('div');
containerImage.className = 'wrap';
elementBodyContent.appendChild(containerImage);

// Create text for imageElement
var textElement = document.createElement('div');
textElement.className = 'text-over-image';
textElement.innerHTML = 'Click to raise simulation';
containerImage.appendChild(textElement);

// Create image of simulation
var imageElement = document.createElement('img');
imageElement.className = 'contrast';
imageElement.width = 700;
imageElement.height = 381;
imageElement.style.cursor = 'pointer'
imageElement.cursor = 'hand';
imageElement.src = 'http://ghujisl.com/Scene.png';
imageElement.onload = function() {
      containerImage.insertBefore(imageElement, textElement);
};
```

and the CSS related :

```
    img.contrast
    {
    filter: contrast(0.3);
            -webkit-filter: contrast(0.3);
            -moz-filter: contrast(0.3);
            -o-filter: contrast(0.3);
            -ms-filter: contrast(0.3);

            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    img.contrast:hover
    {
    filter: contrast(1);
            -webkit-filter: contrast(1);
            -moz-filter: contrast(1);
            -o-filter: contrast(1);
            -ms-filter: contrast(1);

            -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
            -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
            -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    .wrap {
    height:auto;
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    }
   .text-over-image {
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        cursor: pointer;
        top: 0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        color:#fff;
        height:100px;
        }
```

But unfortunately, the transitions are not working correctly. Once I am on the image, sometimes `contrast filter` is applied and sometimes not.

Moreover, when the mouse is over image, if I stop and restart moving mouse, always over the image, the starting image rendering comes back (I get again gray image whereas mouse is still on image).

You can test this strange behavior on the [following link][1].

I did these tests on Firefox 52 and Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133.

If someone could see what's wrong, it would be nice to show me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was your `.text-over-image` div. As it is absolutely positioned above your image, whenever you put your mouse over it, the mouse event is transferred to that div instead of the image. 
An easy fix is to add this to your css:

```
.text-over-image{
   pointer-events : none;
   ...
}
```

I just added the above via chrome inspector while visiting your site, and it fixed the problem for me.